# How can I add three bars to each spot on the Y axis of a plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, statistics

I have a significant three-way interaction that I would like to plot. The three factors are Collection, Variety, and Irrigation, and the response variable is meanGlucCVI. My current idea (open to other suggestions) is to have a bar graph with the meanGlucCVI response on the Y axis and Irrigation on the X axis. At each Irrigation treatment on the X axis, there would be a bar for each Collection treatment. Finally, I would make one of these graphs for each Variety.

My issue is that I don't know how to add the three collection bars into my plots. I've seen graphs that look like this plenty of times, but I'm not solid enough with R to make it happen.

Does this seem like a sensible way to show this data? If so, how could I write code for it? I think that using `ggplot` and its `facetwrap` function might make sense, or maybe just using `ggplot` for the individual graphs and combining them with `gridExtra` from base R (if that's possible.)

Here is my current dataset:

```
dput(head(dataAvgGlucCVI))


structure(list(Collection = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Variety = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Hodag", "Lamoka", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), 
    Irrigation = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("Rate1", 
    "Rate2", "Rate3", "Rate4", "Rate5"), class = "factor"), meanGlucCVI = c(0.03475, 
    0.03475, 0.0455, 0.047, 0.061, 0.04275)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), groups = structure(list(Collection = structure(c(1L, 1L
), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Variety = structure(1:2, .Label = c("Hodag", 
"Lamoka", "Snowden"), class = "factor"), .rows = list(1:5, 6L)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't completely understand what variable should be mapped to what exactly, but here is a go at the first step, which is actually getting a plot. You could give feedback of things you would like to have changed if you find it difficult to code yourself. Assume `df` is generated by `df <- structure(your_dput_output)`.

```
library(ggplot2)

# I'm including a second factor for illustration purposes.
df2 <- df
df2$Collection <- as.factor(2)
# I'm reversing the order of the response to visually distinguish them
df2$meanGlucCVI <- rev(df2$meanGlucCVI)

# Now I'll combine them
df <- rbind(df, df2)

# You give ggplot the data.frame, and map inside aes() what 
# variable you want to map to what aesthetic.
ggplot(df, aes(x = Irrigation, y = meanGlucCVI, fill = Collection)) +
  # We'll dodge the groups (determined by fill) so that they are not stacked
  geom_col(position = position_dodge(width = 0.7), width = 0.6) +
  # You can facet on a variable, for example Variety
  facet_wrap(~ Variety)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing this! This seems like the ideal graph. However, when I run this, I get the error code "Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'meanGlucCVI' not found". Any idea what this means or what I could do to resolve it?

Comment: It probably means that the data.frame that you are using does not contain a column named "meanGlucCVI". You would have to check that this column exists in your data.frame or alternatively, rename `y = meanGlucCVI` to `y = your_other_columname`.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to see what was wrong. This worked great with my data, thanks again for the big help